# Get HTML element CSS Rules server side

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, lxml

I want to load a URL like [this (for ex. bootstarp)](http://getbootstrap.com/) and than point to some element- let's say by a selector ".bs-docs-featurette" and get all it's CSS rules like displayed in FireFox (element inspector F12 >  Rules).

```
element {
}
@media....
.bs-docs-featurette {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.bs-docs-featurette {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(229, 229, 229);
}
```

All in a logical (priority) order, etc.

ComputedStyle is not a option for for me, becouse I lose @media properties, etc.

I have looked into Python's WebDriver (Selenium) and "lxml.cssselect", but non of them gives me a simple solution to my goal.

I prefer stick to Python, but if it's easier in other programming languages, it's OK to shift.

Any good ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use bs4 to do it http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors :)

Comment: Selecting is one part (the easiest) of the job. I don't see an example how to get to Selected element CSS rules tree.

Comment: So an other solution using a js engine like rhino or http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2014/03/nashorn-the-new-rhino-on-the-block.html to execute js server side (http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/). Please update me.